# Spring RestController with Json without eager fetching

Tags: java, json, database, spring, rest

I need to return Json object from Class A using a spring rest controller which converts the object to json.

The thing is that if  we put all the objects inside class A in eager it works but i don't want this because this mean retrieving a chain of object and a lot of information from data base that is not needed.

If i set null to those objects before retrieving object of class A i can solve this but i just don't want this information to be retrieved from the data base.
and either to be displayed on json object. 
I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: ar.com.anovo.business.Model["brand"]->ar.com.anovo.business.Brand_$$_jvst67_6["code"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy
```

Is there any way of havinf objects with Lazy fetching closing the session and having the json retrieved without having any exception?

Thanks in advanced for your replies

Comment: There are many solutions: use a DTO containing only the fields you want to send; use a JSON view, defining only the fields you want to send (https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#jackson-modules); use `@JsonIgnore` to ignore the fields you don't want to send; use the Jackson Hibernate module (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) and configure it to ignore uninitialized proxies.

Comment: jsonIgnore is not an option as it avoids the property in every json returned in every rest service and i want this only for some cases that work with the class not for all the services using the class

Comment: The DTO could work but implicates having a DTO for each class and making a mapper or setting all the desired attributes in each case and is a lot of works (a have a lot of classes i put A to make it generic). And the json view is not an option as we decided to use spring restcontroller to avoid having all the objects mapped to json objects (that' s the advantage of using it). Do you know any other way? Something configurable or something like that? Thank you

Comment: I fail to understand what you want to achieve. It looks like you would like to selectively marshal some fields of an object to JSON, but without ever telling anywhere which fields should be marshaled and which should not. How could that possibly work?